# Why exactly does this short program produce this output?

Tags: c, floating-point

I've had a slow weekend, so just for interest I started working through K.N. King's 'C Programming: A Modern Approach' book today, and started to work through the exercises in the second chapter. One of the exercises is this:

> Write a program that declares several int and float variables - without initialising them - and then prints their values.

My little solution to this is below, including the output. It isn't really a problem as such, I'm just quite curious as to why it does what it does, especially since I'm not so well-informed on lower-level languages.

I had a quick look for some other pre-made solutions on GitHub hoping they'd be commented or something, but its such a simple problem there really was nothing. K.N. King's own site suggests that the pattern of the output depends on, quote, "many factors", but doesn't divulge any more. This is reflected in my output being different to King's.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, num3;    
    float flo1, flo2, flo3;

    printf("Our integers are %d, %d, %d\n", num1, num2, num3); 
    printf("Our floats are %g, %g, %g\n", flo1, flo2, flo3);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is below:

```
C:\C\Intro\exercises>a
Our integers are 0, 16, 0
Our floats are 2.8026e-045, 0, 1.73639e-038
```

Again, not so much a problem, just curious what this is doing, probably at the hardware level.

Comment: Your program invokes *undefined behavior*. Asking "why" regarding observed output is the very definition of futility. You're seeking definition where there is none. You asked "Why". Counter question: *Why not?*. Ex: Why shouldn't `num2` print as `16`? The reasons are just as many (or few) as why it *did*.  King should have covered this in the book (at least I hope so).

Comment: One incorrect way to look at it (other than the correct **Undefined Behaviour**) is that it prints *something* from the last program used. That *something* may be data, instructions, *stack*, ..., garbage

Comment: Memory isn't usually cleared when its freed. Creating these integers/floats allocates new memory to each of them which may or may not be empty. If there is remaining data in the memory at the spot where the int/float is allocated, it won't be cleared and your float/int could have any possible value. As @WhozCraig mentioned, this invokes undefined behavior and should be avoided when developing software as it could lead to strange bugs later on.

Comment: Observed output of undefined behavior really depends on "many factors", some of which may be precisely defined (with a bit of work) and may be fun or enlightening to learn. Waving it off as "undefined behavior" is technically correct but not the best thing to do.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the answer! The explanation in the book is just that accessing uninitialised variables will cause 'strange behaviour', or crash the program. Since as you said it is so unpredictable, it makes sense there isn't much more to cover!

Comment: @WhozCraig: Asking why is not the definition of futile nor futile at all. Asking why, when answered properly, leads to information about how compilers behave and are designed, as well as information about supporting software and about hardware. Curiosity is good and valuable and ought to be encouraged. A manufacturer provides no warranty for what happens when you open a piece of equipment, but doing so may produce useful information and inspire a student.

Comment: @Rowan that explanation is pretty good. In truth, invoking UB can lead to *anything*, or nothing, or worst of all, something that *seems* predictable. The latter is the most offending because the very nature of bad luck will rear its ugly head at the most inopportune time. It may work for you when coding your homework, but crash like a mad dog on your profs evaluation rig. It may work in your development lab, but puke all over itself in your paying customers environment. Just a few reasons UB is to be avoided at all costs (otherwise, different, tangible costs may come in to play).

Comment: @WhozCraig if the result of a discovered undefined behaviour satisfactorily explains some observed but incorrect behaviour in another and apparently unrelated part of the program, there is no futility but satisfaction. In production code just having the side-effect disappear is not as good as *proving* - possibly running further damage and verification tests - that it was fixed. One charateristic of modern software that saddens me is the constant updates and bug fixes that are applied. When manufacturing a product, nothing less than 100% confidence is good enough.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Undefined behavior, as specified by the C standard, should not be avoided at all costs. Most commercial C software relies on undefined behavior. That is because the C standard defines a core language of strictly conforming code, but most useful software needs more than that and uses a mix of strictly conforming, implementation-defined, and undefined behavior (as specified by the C standard). In that realm of undefined behavior lie many useful features, including compiler extensions, linking to code in other languages, and using libraries with functions not possible in base C.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, your code has [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), meaning it could do pretty much whatever it pleases.

In practice, your variables live on the stack but are not initialised.  This likely means they pick up whatever values the stack happens to contain at the locations where the variables get placed by the compiler.  Those values are most likely left over from routines that were called earlier in your process's lifetime, i.e. during its startup.

Comment: Aren't there as many *stacks* as running programs? Or is it a single fixed *stack* chosen by the operating system?

Comment: That is OS- and hardware-specific.  On an OS like Linux (running, say, on x86), each _thread_ has its own stack.  An embedded system might have a very different setup.

Answer (score 1):

First, let’s consider how a very simple compiler might handle this code. When it sees `int num1, num2, num3;` inside a function, it may make space for these on the stack. A stack is commonly how compilers implement objects with automatic storage duration (notably variables defined inside functions that are not `static` or local to a thread). Whenever a new function is called, the compiler writes code to make space on the stack for its local variables and other information. Similarly, space is also allocated for `float flo1, flo2, flo3;`.

Then, when the compiler sees `printf("Our integers are %d, %d, %d\n", num1, num2, num3);`, it generates code to load the values of `num1`, `num2`, and `num3` and to pass them to `printf`. The values are loaded from the memory that was allocated for these objects. What is in that memory? Well, this source code does not assign any values to those objects, so the data in that memory is whatever data was there when the `main` routine started.

What was in that memory? Commonly, when an operating system provides general memory to a process, it clears the memory (sets all bytes in it to zero) so that it does not reveal any data of whatever program used the memory previously. So why are not the `printf` statements printing zeros?

`main` is not actually the start of your program. Before `main` can be executed, something has to set up the C environment. Running a C program requires that any data used by library routines you might call (such as `printf`) be initialized. Also, when the `main` routine returns, it has to have something to return to, something that will take the return value and pass it to the system as a process exit status. That code is also responsible for closing open files and doing some other clean-up work. Commonly, when you link a C program, an extra “start” routine is linked into your executable file. When the operating system starts your program, it calls this “start” routine first, and the start routine sets up the C environment and then calls `main`.

So, when you print `num1`, `num2`, `num3`, `flo1`, `flo2`, and `flo3`, the memory allocated for them has already been used by the “start” routine, and it contains whatever data the “start” routine happened to leave lying around.

That is one explanation for why you see various values printed by this source code.

On the other hand, let’s consider a more sophisticated compiler. A more sophisticated compiler analyzes the code and can see that the variables are used without being initialized. It will warn the user about this, and it also knows that this violates various rules in C. In particular, the C standard does not define what happens when you use an object with automatic storage duration that has been neither initialized nor (for technical/esoteric reasons) had its address taken.

To assist with optimization, sophisticated compilers have special ways of dealing with undefined behavior. For example, if the compiler sees code such as:

```
if (some test)
    FunctionA();
else
{
    Some undefined behavior here…
    FunctionB();
}
```

the compiler can optimize this by “choosing” how to define the undefined behavior. It can define the behavior to alter the program as if it had been written:

```
if (some test)
    FunctionA();
else
{
    FunctionA();
}
```

because that is a valid instance of undefined behavior. Then optimization can proceed to simplify that to:

```
FunctionA();
```

Sometimes cases like this arise in code because a programmer was writing for portability to various environments, and it happens that `some test` indeed cannot be false in a particular compiler, and this optimization produces correct and simple code. Cases like this can also arise where a compiler has been transforming code in other ways and the code above arises not because it was literally written that way in the source code but was generated by the compiler during its internal transformations. For example, a compiler might split a loop into separate code for the first iteration, the general middle iterations, and the last iteration, and `some test` might be always true in the last iteration, even though it was not always true in the context where the programmer wrote it.

What this means is that, when you use undefined behavior (that is not only undefined according to the C standard but also not defined by the C implementation), it may be transformed in ways you do not expect.

I tested this code with a version of LLVM and Clang, and the compiler optimized it by not allocating any memory for the variables and not loading them from memory to pass to `printf`. Instead, it just called `printf` without any preparation for those arguments. In the platform I am using, those arguments are passed in registers. So the result is that `printf` prints whatever values happen to be in those registers. As with the memory, this will be whatever data happened to be left in that memory by earlier software.